# Delay in selection when running iOS app using webkit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, angularjs, webkit

I have been working on writing application on iOS using webkit and AngularJs for front end as I was doing it I experienced a delay while selecting buttons on the pages.So I wrote a directive to implement select on touchstart for the button but still I am getting the delay on selection.

The directive I have written is given below:

```
angular.module('test').directive('fastClick',function(){

    // Runs during compile
    return {       
        restrict: 'A', // E = Element, A = Attribute, C = Class, M = Comment
        link: function($scope, iElm, iAttrs, controller) {

            iElm.bind('touchstart',function(){
                var event = document.createEvent('Event');
                event.initEvent('select', true, true);
                iElm[0].addEventListener('select',true, false);
                iElm[0].dispatchEvent(event);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

And I had disabled zoom on the webpage.

Comment: Do you mean by selecting a click event?

Comment: click on any button the delay occurs

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned in the comments, you are experiencing a delay whenever you click a button. The main reason for the delay is that mobile browsers implement a 300ms delay to decide if the user wants to double-tap to zoom in on the page. I highly recommend [this article](http://blog.ionic.io/hybrid-apps-and-the-curse-of-the-300ms-delay/), which explains the problem in more detail. Basically its the following:

> On touch devices such as phones or tablets, browsers implement a 300ms
>   delay between the time the user stops touching the display and the
>   moment the browser executes the click. It was initially introduced so
>   the browser can tell if the user wants to double-tap to zoom in on the
>   webpage. Basically the browser waits roughly 300ms to see if the user
>   is double-tapping, or just tapping on the display once. While 300ms
>   seems pretty short, it’s surprising just how noticeable it is when you
>   remove the delay.

One possible solution, in case you are not using a hybrid mobile app framework such as Ionic, to use [FastClick](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick).

> FastClick is a simple, easy-to-use library for eliminating the 300ms
>   delay between a physical tap and the firing of a click event on mobile
>   browsers.

Also, if you decide to use FastClick I suggest to initialize it in a `run` block like so:

```
angular.module('myModule', [])
  .run(function() {
    FastClick.attach(document.body);
  });
```

FastCklick is heavily tested, widely used and works great on many devices.

Another option is to use [ngTouch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngTouch). However, ngTouch overrides ngClick and hence only removes the delay on elements that have the `ng-click` attribute.